# Laravel API request prepending "<?php"

Tags: javascript, api, laravel-5, axios

**My Problem**

Simply put, I have two systems that work together, one thats plain html and uses Axios to send requests to my laravel application and the other is the laravel application which is basically just an API for the first application. When I make a request to the laravel api I keep getting data back that is prepended with the `<?php`" opening tag which is causing all sorts of random problems!

**Javascript**

```
axios.post('http://my.app.test/api/authenticate').then((response) => {
    let data = response.data;
        console.log(data);
    });
```

**Laravel - api.php**

```
Route::middleware('api')->group(function(){
    Route::post('/authenticate', function(Request $request){
        return [
            'something',
            'something else'
        ];
    });
});
```

**Result**

```
<?php["something","something else"]
```

Any insight as to why this is happening will be helpful. If anymore information is needed please ask and ill provide! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RouteServiceProvider.php` contains:

```
public function map(Router $router)
{
    $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router)
    {
        foreach (File::allFiles(app_path('Http/Routes')) as $partial)
        {
            require_once($partial->getPathname());
        }
    });
}
```

One of the route files loaded by this method probably has nothing in it except for a `<?php` tag with **no new line**. The absence of a new line is probably the issue.

Comment: Perfect, because the Routeserviceprovider was loading my web.php and that file had no routes in because im using my api.php. Basically whether you're using web.php or not, it should not be left blank.

Answer (score 1):

The code above looks fine, but then again I don't think the problem lies there.

This sounds like you have a `<?php` in either laravel (unlikely) or in your static html file somewhere.
Check your laravel index.php or config files for additional "`<?php`".
And search your html and javascript file for "`<?php`"

Comment: Ive looked through, there is none. its being sent by Laravel for sure I remember having this exact problem a few years ago but cant remember how to solve it